# wp8.1 rt graphing libraries

Tags: plot, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to display a scatter plot for a windows 8.1 universal app but unfortunately all the libraries on NuGet.org give the following error when installing to the phone:

```
Could not install package 'OxyPlot.Core 2014.1.312.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references
```

Are there any data-visualization or graphing libraries that are compatible with windows phone 8.1 rt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know telerik has compatible libs in a public beta. But I'm not sure if they contain the graphs you need.

http://blogs.telerik.com/windowsphoneteam/posts/14-04-08/telerik-ready-for-microsoft-universal-windows-apps

In the meanwhile they updated the beta twice and they are close to a public release.

Regards
NPadrutt